# Symfony2.8 fatal error with monolog and swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, monolog

I recently encountered the following error on ubuntu server with php7 and Symfony2.8.*:

> Fatal error: Cannot use $this as parameter in
>   app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line xxx

The target line is inside this block:

```
public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, $fromEmail, $toEmail, $subject, $contentType = null)
{
    static $reflection;
    if (! $this->valueHolder575050505c85a273560796) {
        $reflection = $reflection ?: new \ReflectionClass('Symfony\\Bundle\\MonologBundle\\SwiftMailer\\MessageFactory');
        $this->valueHolder575050505c85a273560796 = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
    \Closure::bind(function (\Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\SwiftMailer\MessageFactory $this) {
        unset($this->mailer, $this->fromEmail, $this->toEmail, $this->subject, $this->contentType);
    }, $this, 'Symfony\\Bundle\\MonologBundle\\SwiftMailer\\MessageFactory')->__invoke($this);
    }
    $this->valueHolder575050505c85a273560796->__construct($mailer, $fromEmail, $toEmail, $subject, $contentType);
}
```

And, more specifically, the *xxx* line is :
 `\Closure::bind(function (\Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\SwiftMailer\MessageFactory $this) {`

I tried to change monolog versions, swiftmailer versions, event symfony versions but the problem still occurs and blocks all my app. I've then disabled logs by emails for now, but I'd like to fix it. Any ideas ?
Locally on my Mac, all is running fine.

Comment: Take a look if you are using the same version in both machines. If you are using composer, look at your composer.json. Also, check if your php versions are all the same.

Comment: composer.json and composer.lock are the sames in both machines, however the php version is 7.0.7-2+donate.sury.org~trusty+1 on my ubuntu server and 7.0.6 on my mac. As you suggest I'll try with the same php versions, I've not thought about it

Comment: https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager/pull/308 : it seems that PHP 7.0.7 changed something that breaks some libs. That's probably your issue here. Try using php 7.0.6 in both machines until they fix your lib.

Comment: I had no time yet to test with PHP 7.0.6 as I need to find a deb with this version or to build mine. However, I'm almost sure you're right. I also see in the changelog of PHP 7.0.7 that a bug has been fixed and it could be the reason of my problem : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71737 (#71737 Memory leak in closure with parameter named $this)

Comment: @Seb do you fix this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Alex I disabled logs by email, this is the only solution I found now with php >=7.0.7. I still wait for the lib updates. If you can, try to use php <= 7.0.6 until they fix it, as suggested by Felippe